# How to Do Backtracking Line Search for Proximal Gradient Decent?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning, proximal-operators

I have problem in following form:
Let $X\in R^{N\times M}$ denote feature matrix for $M$ features and $Y\in R^{N\times T}$  be response matrix for $N$ data points over $T$ variables.
I have function $$f(X) + h(W)$$
where $f(W)=||Y-XW||_F^2$
I solve this with proximal gradient decent where I have proximal operator of $h(W)$

Step I : 
Compute gradient: 
$$W^{t+1}=W-s\nabla f(W)$$
Step II: $$prox_h(W^{t+1})$$
Where $s$ is step size. I want to use backtracking line search for selecting step-size. I know how to do it, if $Y$ and $W$ were vectors. But seems that it gets more complicated when I extend it to matrix form.\

Here is how people do it for the case where $Y$ and $W$ are vectors:

\begin{equation}
G_s(W)= \frac{W-prox_s(W - s\nabla f(W))}{s}
\end{equation}

Step I

Fix a parameter $0<\beta<1$

Step II

At each iteration we start with $s=1$, and while

$$f(W-s * G_s(W))>f(W)-s\nabla f(W)^T * (G_s(W)) + \frac{1}{2}||(G_s(W)||^2_2$$ shrink $s=\beta s$. Else perform prox gradient update

\end{equation}

Whem $W$ amd $Y$ are vectors, it's easy. since $$s\nabla f(W)^T*G_s(W)$$ is constant (inner product of two vectors), but when $W$ is matrix, then it become matrix and we can not evaluate above equation.
Does anybody have better solution backtraking line search for this case ?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @Royi, Not really ....

Comment: Could you please mark my answer?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is:

$$ \left \langle s \nabla f \left( W \right), {G}_{s} \left( W \right) \right \rangle $$

Well, the most common inner product for matrices is the [Trace Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)):

$$ \left \langle s \nabla f \left( W \right), {G}_{s} \left( W \right) \right \rangle = \operatorname{Tr} \left( {s \nabla f \left( W \right)}^{T} {G}_{s} \left( W \right) \right) $$